# Image Zoomer tool in c#

Tags: c#, zooming, picturebox, trackbar

I am trying to make a trackbar which will zoom in and out on a picture in a picturebox. This is my current code:

```
namespace Zoom_in_and_Out_Tool
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Image imgOriginal;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // set image location
        imgOriginal = Image.FromFile(@"C:\New Folder\picture1.jpg");
        picBox.Image = imgOriginal;

        // set Picture Box Attributes
        picBox.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;

        // set Slider Attributes
        zoomSlider.Minimum = 1;
        zoomSlider.Maximum = 5;
        zoomSlider.SmallChange = 1;
        zoomSlider.LargeChange = 1;
        zoomSlider.UseWaitCursor = false;

        // reduce flickering
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        }

        public Image PictureBoxZoom(Image img, Size size)
        {
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(img, Convert.ToInt32(img.Width * size.Width), Convert.ToInt32(img.Height * size.Height));
        Graphics grap = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        grap.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        return bm;
        }

        private void zoomSlider_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (zoomSlider.Value > 0)
            {
            picBox.Image = null;
            picBox.Image = PictureBoxZoom(imgOriginal, new Size(zoomSlider.Value, zoomSlider.Value));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently it comes up with 2 problems. One being it does want to compile with the line   grap.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic; . The Second problem is that when i try to zoom it comes up with the error: " "ArgumentException was unhandled" error at the line: Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(img, Convert.ToInt32(img.Width * size.Width), Convert.ToInt32(img.Height * size.Height)); " Any help would be great,

Thanks

**UPDATE**
The first error says: "The name 'InterpolationMode' does not exist in the current context"
The second error when i comment this line out is: 'NullReferenceException was unhandled "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' on the line Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(img, Convert.ToInt32(img.Width * size.Width), Convert.ToInt32(img.Height * size.Height));

Thanks

Comment: What's the complilation error for the first and the inner exception details for the second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include

```
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
```

in your using list.

The second error could be due to either the `img` being null or the `size` being null.

Answer (score -1):

The **first** compiler error is more than likely caused by an unknown reference to `InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic`. The `InterpolationMode` enumeration is found in the `Drawing2D` namespace, which is a child namespace of `System.Drawing`.

You can fix this error either by adding an additional `Using` directive for `System.Drawing.Drawing2D`, or by fully qualifying the namespace in your code:

```
grap.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
```

The **second** problem with your code is that the image you're specifying as a parameter to this method (`img`) is a null reference. The `Scroll` event of your zoom slider is probably getting raised as soon as the control is created (in your form's constructor), which is before the code in your form's `Load` method is run, which is what creates the image (by loading it from a file on disk).

Try adding a null check to the `Scroll` event handler:

```
    private void zoomSlider_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if ((zoomSlider.Value > 0) && (imgOriginal != null))
        {
        picBox.Image = null;
        picBox.Image = PictureBoxZoom(imgOriginal, new Size(zoomSlider.Value, zoomSlider.Value));
        }
    }
```

**Finally**, I noticed that you're setting the `BackgroundImageLayout` property of the picture box, but none of the code you post is actually specifying a background image for the picture box. Did you mean to set the [`SizeMode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx) to adjust how the image is displayed? Something like:

```
picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```